# Why can't we set the value of static final variable in static block through class name

Tags: java, static, final, static-block

For example, consider code snap below:

```
public static final int a;
public static final int b;

static {
    a = 8;       // it's working
    Test.b = 10; // compilation error Test.b cannot be assigned. 
}
```

Why can't we use `Test.b = 10;` inside a static block of the `Test` class itself? Without the class name it's working fine.

Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Because your class is not yet initialized when you are in a static initializer? Also probably because the JLS forbids it...

Comment: Are you interested in "which bit of the JLS prohibits this" or "why was the language designed this way"?

Comment: Could be wrong here, but perhaps its because you have `Test.b` declared as `final`

Comment: @JSKNS it is true that removing the `final` modifier makes the error go away, but the question is why.

Comment: because you can't modify final variables after they've been initialized.

Comment: @JSKNS: Where do you see it being initialized at the moment, other than that assignment? And how do you see that changing if you remove the `Test.` part?

Comment: The error goes away if you remove the `final` modifier, and the error I get from the compiler (Java 8) is `cannot assign a value to final variable y`, so the `final` is certainly significant.

Comment: Are you looking for a secret Winter Bash hat for accumulating deleted answers on a question...?

Answer (score 10):

A static final variable must be initialized before use. It may be initialized either directly at declaration time, or in a static block.

But when you use `class.var = x` it is not seen as an initialization but as an assignation.

With a JDK 7, the error is *cannot assign a value to final variable*.

That explains why it works if you remove the `final` keyword

```
class Test {

    static final int a = 2; // initialization at declaration time
    static final int b;
    static final int c;

    static {
        b = 4;  // initialization in static block
        Test.c = 6; // error : cannot assign a value to final variable c
    }
    ...

}
```

EDIT

In the JLS the correct word for initialization is *definite assignement*

Extract from the JLS :

*For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be definitely
assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.*

*Similarly, every blank final variable must be assigned at most once; it must be
definitely unassigned when an assignment to it occurs.*

*Such an assignment is defined to occur if and only if either **the simple name of the
variable (or, for a field, its simple name qualified by this)** occurs on the left hand
side of an assignment operator.*

*For every assignment to a blank final variable, the variable must be definitely
unassigned before the assignment, or a compile-time error occurs.*

emphasize mine, but I think this is the real reason for the error.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right, though it must be along the right lines. This says that you can't assign to a blank final variable unless it's definitely unassigned at that point, but it is definitely unassigned. It doesn't seem to me to violate the bit you quote.

Comment: @chiastic-security : I'm not really a lawyer, and english is not my first language, by I think that the important word here is *simple name* because `Test.b` is not a simple name.

Comment: Yes, that phrase is important, but all it says is that `Test.b = 10` isn't "such an assignment", i.e., this code isn't in view for this bit of the JLS.

Comment: @chiastic-security : You are right. I forgot the first line of the paragraph that states *For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be definitely
assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.*. Added.

Comment: I read that, but I'm not convinced it helps. The code doesn't *access* the field at all; it only assigns to it. (As far as I can see, *access* implies a read operation.)

Comment: @chiastic-security : As I said english is not my first language and I thought *access* could be a write as well as a read what would be coherent with the text of the error.

Comment: It's really hard to pinpoint in the JLS. You could argue that, since final fields can only be assigned once, and an assignment through something that's not a simple name doesn't cause definite assignment, and definite assignment is required at the end of the static block; then assignment not through a simple name must be forbidden because it precludes correct definite assignment.